# How to set permissions for hg init in Mercurial?

Tags: ubuntu, version-control, mercurial, ubuntu-20.04

I am running Mercurial 6.2.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

I can run `hg init` without any problems in the home directory.

However the same command on a mounted disk fails with the following error:

`abort: Permission denied: '/media/DISK1/Respository/.hg'`

The error message does not make sense because Repository is completely empty (no `.hg` in it). I have used the disk for years, including e.g. for Git without any issues.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: In Repository, the command `touch test && ls -l test` returns

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Jun  1 21:47 test`

Comment: You should edit the question to add information, you don't have to add it in a comment

Comment: Maybe it is failing when trying to create the .hg directory?   Can you create a directory yourself in that location as the same user, as a test?

Comment: Thanks for your tip. If I create .hg first, then `hg init` will complain `abort: repository . already exists`

Comment: another test - run hg init somewhere else and then copy that repo to the mounted location

Comment: That's just kicking the can down the road because then `hg pull` returns `abort: Permission denied: '/media/DISK1/Repository/.hg/requires'`

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is an hg problem to me. Maybe you should ask about this on superuser.com where people may be more focused on the linux permissions side of things?

Comment: You can use `strace` to see the system calls, like `strace -o /tmp/logfile hg init`. Maybe you can see something there.